# What are the new spells and where can I find them?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

I am searching for the two new spells in the Falskaar mod, but I had no luck so far. Anyone know where I can start looking for them?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know.

Comment: Could you specify a little cause i searched for the whole place and found nothing

Answer (score 3):

The two new spells added by Falskaar are *Relentless Spirit* and *Fury of Flames*. Their spell tomes can be found in Vizemundsted.